# How to pass Travis CI test for python click.version_option decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, pytest, travis-ci

I was trying to pass the following test in Travis CI for my `click` application:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def runner():
    return CliRunner()  # from click.testing import CliRunner
    enter code here


def test_cli_with_version(runner):
    result = runner.invoke(cli.main, ['--version'])
    assert result.exit_code == 0
    assert not result.exception
    assert result.output.strip()
```

Target function was a standard `click` group function.

```py
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@click.help_option(help='Show help index and exit')
@click.version_option(message='%(prog)s v%(version)s', help='Show the version and exit')
@click.option('-p', '--profile', default='dev', help='Set configuration profile')
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, profile='dev'):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        click.echo(click.style(title, fg='green'))

    ctx.obj = ContextConfig().load_for(profile)
```

The goal of the test was to simulate a command that looked like `main --version`.

When I ran this test in my local environment, it passed (along with the others).

```sh
$ pytest
============================ test session starts ============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/root/dir
collected 15 items                                                          

tests/test_cli.py ..........                                          [ 66%]
tests/test_contexts.py .                                              [ 73%]
tests/test_models.py .                                                [ 80%]
tests/test_utils.py ...                                               [100%]

============================ 15 passed in 0.30s =============================
```

However, when Travis tried to build it, this particular test failed. Here's the debug log from Travis

```sh
$ pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/root/dir
collected 15 items                                                             
tests/test_cli.py ..F.......                                             [ 66%]
tests/test_contexts.py .                                                 [ 73%]
tests/test_models.py .                                                   [ 80%]
tests/test_utils.py ...                                                  [100%]
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ test_cli_with_version _____________________________
runner = <click.testing.CliRunner object at 0x7fe288f596a0>
    def test_cli_with_version(runner):
        result = runner.invoke(cli.main, ['--version'])
>       assert result.exit_code == 0
E       AssertionError: assert 1 == 0
E        +  where 1 = <Result RuntimeError('Could not determine version',)>.exit_code
tests/test_cli.py:35: AssertionError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests/test_cli.py::test_cli_with_version - AssertionError: assert 1 == 0
========================= 1 failed, 14 passed in 0.34s =========================
The command "pytest" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

It looked like click.version_option decorator was failing to read version string in Travis CI's environment. Versioning for the repo was maintained by `setuptools-scm` library. However, I have not add any tag to master branch yet.

Here's how `.travis.yml` file looks like:

```yaml
language: python
# target python versions
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
  - "3.8"
# operating systems
os:
  - linux
  - osx
  - windows
# configure jobs
jobs:
  allow_failures:
    - os: windows
    - os: osx
# install dependencies
install:
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
# run tests
script:
  - pytest
# target branches for builds
branches:
  only:
    - master
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Install the package in editable mode: `pip install --editable .`, just after you install the requirements. You can even combine those two: `pip install -r requirements.txt --editable .`

Comment: @hoefling thanks :) It worked!! I was also thinking about adding another pip install command to install the application packages, but wasn't sure that would do anything. Evidently, it fixed the issue. Please add your solution as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer:

You need to generate package metadata so the version can be read from. This can be done in different ways, the minimal being

```
$ python setup.py egg_info
```

However, much better is installing the package in editable mode:

```
$ pip install --editable .
```

For Travis, just add another command to the `install` section:

```
install:
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install --editable .
```

You can even combine all three commands into one:

```
- pip install --upgrade pip -r requirements.txt --editable .
```